# `fastboot devices` command returns a device with question marks

Tags: rooting, adb, fastboot

I am trying to root an Acer Iconia Tab A200 tablet using a script. I have adb working and fastboot works too, however, command `fastboot devices` returns question marks. E.g.:

```
List of devices attached
20819705215     device

$ fastboot devices
$ adb reboot-bootloader
$ fastboot devices
????????????    fastboot
$ _
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of the terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar84d.png)</sup>

I execute the command `fastboot devices` in the bootloader which is already unlocked. Using Ubuntu 14.04, udev settings are already set (the file with vendors IDs) according to the ID result of the command `lsusb`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3201", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="ln"
```

What can I do to get the correct result? How can I make fastboot work well?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a cable fault. Change the cable. In my Redmi 3 on a cable from an old Xperia P, I've had question marks. When I replaced the cable with a newer cable from Redmi Note 2 and voila - the correct number was displayed instead of the question marks.

Comment: Wow ! changing cables for me worked too. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux, try `sudo fastboot devices`. I found that was needed with a later Linux than you have (RHEL7.9).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the phone, an unsupported/rogue Chinese firmware that had the option "fastboot" but was really just a nickname for a type of connection supported by their own software. Tried my setup (cable + PC) on different, 3, phones and it all worked except this one. Even the brand was murky with the only label on it being "k48".